# Spark mapPartitions correct usage with DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm struggling with the correct usage of `mapPartitions`.

I've successfully run my code with `map`, however since I do not want the resources to be loaded for every row I'd like to switch to `mapPartitions`.

Here's some simple example code:

```
import spark.implicits._
val dataDF = spark.read.format("json").load("basefile")
val newDF = dataDF.mapPartitions( iterator  => {
  iterator.map(p => Seq(1,"1")))
}).toDF("id", "newContent")
newDF.write.json("newfile")
```

This causes the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Any
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with typing. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that `Seq(1,"1")` is of type `Seq[Any]` which can't be returned from `mapPartitions`, try `Seq(1,2)` intsead if that works